# How to delete multiple values from a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector like: `a = c(1:10)` and I need to remove multiple values, like: `2, 3, 5`

How to delete those numbers (they are **NOT** the positions in the vector) in the vector?

at the moment i loop the vector and do something like:

```
a[!a=NUMBER_TO_REMOVE]
```

But I think there is a function that does it automatically.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

The `%in%` operator tells you which elements are among the numers to remove:

```
> a <- sample (1 : 10)
> remove <- c (2, 3, 5)
> a
 [1] 10  5  2  7  1  6  3  4  8  9
> a %in% remove
 [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> a [! a %in% remove]
 [1] 10  7  1  6  4  8  9
```

Note that this will silently remove incomparables (stuff like `NA` or `Inf)` as well (while it will keep duplicate values in `a` as long as they are not listed in `remove`).

- If `a` can contain incomparables, but `remove` will not, we can use `match`, telling it to return `0` for non-matches and incomparables (`%in%` is a conventient shortcut for `match`):

  ```
  > a <- c (a, NA, Inf)
  > a
   [1]  10   5   2   7   1   6   3   4   8   9  NA Inf
  > match (a, remove, nomatch = 0L, incomparables = 0L)
   [1] 0 3 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
  > a [match (a, remove, nomatch = 0L, incomparables = 0L) == 0L]
  [1]  10   7   1   6   4   8   9  NA Inf
  ```

  `incomparables = 0` is not *needed* as incomparables will anyways not match, but I'd include it for the sake of readability.
  This is, btw., what `setdiff` does internally (but without the `unique` to throw away duplicates in `a` which are not in `remove`).
- If `remove` contains incomparables, you'll have to check for them individually, e.g.

  ```
  if (any (is.na (remove))) 
    a <- a [! is.na (a)]
  ```

  (This does not distinguish `NA` from `NaN` but the R manual anyways warns that one should not rely on having a difference between them)

  For `Inf`/ `-Inf` you'll have to check both `sign` and `is.finite`

Comment: `setdiff` is better, as it does everything in one operation, and references the amended vector only once.

Comment: @Olexa: set difference is not always the same as removing all occurences of a given set of numbers from a vector: it will remove duplicates in `a` that are not in `remove` as well. If that's not a problem, you can also use `setdiff`. `setdiff`, btw, uses `match` for which `%in%` is a shortcut.

Answer (score 117):

You can use `setdiff`.

Given

```
a <- sample(1:10)
remove <- c(2, 3, 5)
```

Then

```
> a
 [1] 10  8  9  1  3  4  6  7  2  5
> setdiff(a, remove)
[1] 10  8  9  1  4  6  7
```

Comment: very useful when `a` is the result of another function so you can do things in one line instead of 3 and a temp variable

Comment: This will produce different results than the `%in%` solution if the input vector contains duplicates (in which case `setdiff` will only return the unique _set_, i.e. without duplicates)

Comment: @docendodiscimus: `fsetdiff` of `data.table` package has an `all` flag (default F) that allows to keep duplicates in the input vector.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it as follows:

```
> x<-c(2, 4, 6, 9, 10) # the list
> y<-c(4, 9, 10) # values to be removed

> idx = which(x %in% y ) # Positions of the values of y in x
> idx
[1] 2 4 5
> x = x[-idx] # Remove those values using their position and "-" operator
> x
[1] 2 6
```

Shortly

```
> x = x[ - which(x %in% y)]
```

Comment: what you're calling a list in your example is a vector, right?

Comment: Yes I mean the vector. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: There is no need in `which` here. It's basically the same as @cbeleites answer.

Comment: yes it is similar, but different in a few points of view. `which` returns indexes of TRUE values. So minus sign can be used to say "the indexes other than these indexes". Also `which` is more readable since it is closer to the natural language.

Answer (score 10):

instead of

```
x <- x[! x %in% c(2,3,5)]
```

using the packages `purrr` and `magrittr`, you can do:

```
your_vector %<>% discard(~ .x %in% c(2,3,5))
```

this allows for `subset`ting using the vector name only once. And you can use it in pipes :)

Comment: can you please explain your last statement about variables name length? Why you don't like that? Why is better than the other way? Or, remove that paragraph since is not related to the main issue/question.

Answer (score 4):

First we can define a new operator,

```
"%ni%" = Negate( "%in%" )
```

Then, its like x not in remove

```
x <- 1:10
remove <- c(2,3,5)
x <- x[ x %ni% remove ]
```

or why to go for remove, go directly

```
x <- x[ x %ni% c(2,3,5)]
```

Comment: The question specifically says that 2, 3 and 5 are not positions in the vector.

Answer (score 3):

There is also `subset` which might be useful sometimes:

```
a <- sample(1:10)
bad <- c(2, 3, 5)

> subset(a, !(a %in% bad))
[1]  9  7 10  6  8  1  4
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

All of the above answers won't work for the repeated values, @BenBolker's answer using `duplicated()` predicate solves this:

```
full_vector[!full_vector %in% searched_vector | duplicated(full_vector)]
```

**Original Answer:**
 here I write a little function for this:

```
exclude_val<-function(full_vector,searched_vector){

      found=c()

      for(i in full_vector){  

        if(any(is.element(searched_vector,i))){
          searched_vector[(which(searched_vector==i))[1]]=NA
        }
        else{
          found=c(found,i)
        }
    }

    return(found)
}
```

so, let's say `full_vector=c(1,2,3,4,1)` and `searched_vector=c(1,2,3)`.

`exclude_val(full_vector,searched_vector)` will return (4,1), however above answers will return just `(4)`.

Comment: what about `full_vector[!full_vector %in% searched_vector | duplicated(full_vector)]` ?

Comment: @BenBolker  ah I didn't know that "duplicated" predicate :(( now what, shall I delete my answer or change it to show only yours instead?

Comment: @BenBolker, your solution is wrong; just try: `full_vector = c(1,1,1,2,3); searched_vector = c(1,1,3);` - that produces `1, 1, 2` instead of the correct answer `1, 2`.

Comment: Just to add a possible, correct solution for repeated values: `removeif <- function(from, where) { for (i in where) if (i %in% from) {from = from[-match(i, from)]}; from}`

Answer (score 1):

```
q <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,7)
rm <- q[11]
remove(rm)
q
q[13] = NaN
q
q %in% 7
```

This sets the 13 in a vector to not a number(NAN) it shows false
remove(q[c(11,12,13)])
if you try this you will see that remove function don't work on vector number.
you remove entire vector but maybe not a single element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```
seq.int.exclude <- function(excluded, ...) {
    x <- seq.int(...)
    return(x[!(x %in% excluded)])
}
```

Call examples:

```
seq.int.exclude(from = 10L, to = 20L, excluded = c(12L, 30L, 19L))
seq.int.exclude(from = 10L, to = 20L, excluded = 15L)
```