# Remove a particular group of elements in a vector?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete multiple values from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665984/how-to-delete-multiple-values-from-a-vector)

Is there any build-in function allowing us to remove a particular group of
elements in a vector ?

example:

```
x<-c(2, 4, 6, 9, 10)
```

remove the vector `c(4,9,10)` from `x`

Answer (score 27):

you can do this many ways here is one:

```
x[!x %in% c(4, 9, 10)]
```

Comment: if you want to use which, you can do: x[which(!x %in% c(4,9,10))]

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively you could use `?is.element`

```
x[!is.element(x, c(4,9,10))]
```

Comment: You forgot the close paren on `is.element`.

Answer (score 8):

This could be useful

```
 x<-c(2, 4, 6, 9, 10)
 y <- c(4,9,10)
 setdiff(x, y)
 2 6
```

Comment: Only caveat here is that `setdiff` performs a set operation. So if `x <-c(2,4,6,9,10,2)`, then `setdiff` still returns `2 6` where one might expect `2 6 2`.

Comment: @mindless.panda you're completely right, in that case one should use x[!x%in%y] as jmsigner suggests.