# Fill missing replicate values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 6 replicates for each group on each date. As you can see in a sub-sample of the data below, the replicate number (1-6) is missing for some, but not all cells. For each Group within Date cluster, I would like to fill in empty cells with the replicate values that are missing for that cluster. For example, if replicate "3" is the only replicate currently labeled, I would like to label the 5 remaining cells in that cluster as "1", "2", "4", "5", and "6", with the added replicates being placed in no particular order.

The Data I have look like this:

```
   Date   Group Value   Replicate
8/8/2002    A   77.8         3
8/8/2002    A    0  
8/8/2002    A    0  
8/8/2002    A    0  
8/8/2002    A    0  
8/8/2002    A    0  
6/28/2003   A   88.9         1
6/28/2003   A   66.7         3
6/28/2003   A   44.4         4
6/28/2003   A   88.9         6
6/28/2003   A    0  
6/28/2003   A   144.4   
6/28/2006   B   988.9        2
6/28/2006   B    0  
6/28/2006   B    0  
6/28/2006   B    0  
6/28/2006   B    0  
6/28/2006   B    0  
8/5/2006    B   122.2        1
8/5/2006    B   11.1         2
8/5/2006    B   55.6         3
8/5/2006    B   55.6         4
8/5/2006    B   88.9         5
8/5/2006    B   177.8        6
```

I would like to have the data look like this

```
Date    Group   Value   Replicate
8/8/2002    A   77.8      3
8/8/2002    A     0       1
8/8/2002    A     0       2
8/8/2002    A     0       4
8/8/2002    A     0       5
8/8/2002    A     0       6
6/28/2003   A   88.9      1
6/28/2003   A   66.7      3
6/28/2003   A   44.4      4
6/28/2003   A   88.9      6
6/28/2003   A     0       2
6/28/2003   A   144.4     5
6/28/2006   B   988.9     2
6/28/2006   B     0       3
6/28/2006   B     0       4
6/28/2006   B     0       5
6/28/2006   B     0       6
6/28/2006   B     0       1
8/5/2006    B   122.2     1
8/5/2006    B   11.1      2
8/5/2006    B   55.6      3
8/5/2006    B   55.6      4
8/5/2006    B   88.9      5
8/5/2006    B   177.8     6
```

Is there an efficient way to fill in these missing replicate values using R (my dataset has ~20,000 rows)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a little custom function to do the replacement for you and then use some data manipulation package like dplyr to apply the function by group of Date. Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x) {
  na_idx <- which(is.na(x))
  unique_elements <- unique(x[-na_idx])
  set_diff <- setdiff(1:6, unique_elements)
  x[na_idx] <- set_diff
  x
}

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(Replicate = f(Replicate))  # you could add %>% ungroup if required

#Source: local data frame [24 x 4]
#Groups: Date
#
#        Date Group Value Replicate
#1   8/8/2002     A  77.8         3
#2   8/8/2002     A   0.0         1
#3   8/8/2002     A   0.0         2
#4   8/8/2002     A   0.0         4
#5   8/8/2002     A   0.0         5
#6   8/8/2002     A   0.0         6
#7  6/28/2003     A  88.9         1
#8  6/28/2003     A  66.7         3
#9  6/28/2003     A  44.4         4
#10 6/28/2003     A  88.9         6
#..       ...   ...   ...       ...
```

You could probably write the function with a little less rows / typing but I find it easier to read and follow with 1 operation done per row, therefore I'll leave it as it is.

---

Note: when reading in your data, I used `fill = TRUE` parameter so that empty cells ("" entries) were filled with `NA`. If you need to convert your current data to that format you could do something like:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  if(is.character(x)) {
    x[x == ""] <- NA; type.convert(x)
  } else x
  })
```

This is useful because in your sample data with "" entries, columns that *should* be numeric are characters and hence you cannot use them for mathematical operations.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The first function you provided worked great on the sample data set, but I needed to add "Group" to the group_by function in order for it to work on my larger dataset. It appears to have turned out fine, however I did receive 50 warnings, each indicating that "In x[na_idx] <- set_diff : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". I can't find any errors in the newly created dataset, so I'm sure how to proceed with this error. I will keep investigating though. 

All in all, the code worked great for the sample data! Thanks again.

Comment: @Strom, I saw your comment only now. Since it seems to work for the sample data, it's hard to tell what doesn't work in the actual data. The error message indicates that the number of `NA` or `""` entries in your real data is different than the items you try to replace and because the vector used for replacing is recycled, it generates warnings (that's my interpretation). Would be easier if you could provide a minimal sample datat for which the warning message appears

Answer (score 0):

here's another approach that should do the trick, without using dplyr or lapply

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665984/how-to-delete-multiple-values-from-a-vector
# your.data is your data
dates <- unique(your.data$Date)
for(date in dates){
    this.date <- your.data[ which(your.data$Date == date), ]
    remove <- this.date$Replicate
    full.rep <- 1:6
    fill <- full.rep [! full.rep %in% remove]
    fill <- sample(fill) # randomize fill
    this.date[ which(!(this.date$Replicate %in% remove)), ]$Replicate <- fill
    your.data[ which(your.data$Date == date), ] <- this.date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(dt, Date)[is.na(Replicate), 
        Replicate := setdiff(1:6, dt[.(thisDate), Replicate]), 
        by=.(thisDate=Date)]
```

- First we get the indices where `Replicate` is `NA` by doing `is.na(Replicate)`.
- On those rows of `dt` where `Replicate` is `NA`, we group by `Date` (we rename it to another name so that we can use it in a join in the next step).
- So, for each set of rows where `Replicate` is `NA` while grouped by `thisDate`, we first extract all `Replicate` values by performing a join based subset - `dt[.(thisDate), Replicate]`. Then `setdiff(1:6, <all Replicate values>)` returns just the remaining values. We assign it back to `Replicate` with `Replicate :=`

Hope this helps.