# Remove certain values from a list of vectors

Tags: r

I have a vector with some characters:

The structure `glimpse(a)`

```
List of 5
 $ : chr [1:2] "Thai" "Restaurants"
 $ : chr [1:2] "Vietnamese" "Restaurants"
 $ : chr [1:3] "Restaurants" "Vegetarian" "Indian"
 $ : chr [1:5] "Nightlife" "Bars" "Restaurants" "Thai" ...
 $ : chr [1:4] "Asian Fusion" "Chinese" "Japanese" "Restaurants"
```

Here is a `dput(a)`

```
list(c("Thai", "Restaurants"), c("Vietnamese", "Restaurants"), 
    c("Restaurants", "Vegetarian", "Indian"), c("Nightlife", 
    "Bars", "Restaurants", "Thai", "Sports Bars"), c("Asian Fusion", 
    "Chinese", "Japanese", "Restaurants"))
```

I want to drop some values by exclusion. For example, the values below are the only values which should stay in the vector. All other values should be removed, with no replacement.

```
c("Chinese", "Japanese", "Sushi Bars", "Indian", "Thai", "Vietnamese", "Korean","Taiwanese", "Malaysian", "Mongolian", "Indonesian", "Laotian", "Myanmar", "Pan Asian", "Tempura", "Wok")
```

So, I tried the solution from this post:
[How to delete multiple values from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665984/how-to-delete-multiple-values-from-a-vector)

So I did:

```
rm <-  c("Chinese", "Japanese", "Sushi Bars", "Indian", "Thai", "Vietnamese", "Korean","Taiwanese", "Malaysian", "Mongolian", "Indonesian", "Laotian", "Myanmar", "Pan Asian", "Tempura", "Wok")

a [! a %in% rm]
```

But nothing changes?!. Anny Idea how to remove those values from `a` that doesn't belong to `rm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `setdiff` if the elements are `unique` by looping over the `list` elements with `lapply`

```
lapply(a,  setdiff, rm)
```

Or else, use `%in%` and then negate

```
lapply(a, function(x) x[!x %in% rm])
```

Comment: I want the opposite from that what your code does. But if I drop the `!` from the second one, it works just fine!

Comment: or try this `library(tidyverse); a %>% map(function(x) x[ ! x %in% rm])`