# How to delete multiple values from a vector? But not all of them

Tags: r

Say I have two vectors,

```
set <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8, 8, 10)
played <- c(1, 3, 1, 4)
```

I want to remove the "played" numbers from the original set, **but** I don't want to remove all of the 1, 3 or 4's. 
Such that the resulting vector should be,

```
1,1,3,4,8,8,10
```

At the moment I am using a loop but this is not a very efficient method. Is there a function to do what I want.

Note: This is not a duplicate of Not a duplicate of 
[How to delete multiple values from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665984/how-to-delete-multiple-values-from-a-vector)
but rather an expansion, all about not removing all of the values.

Re-Edit: I said order matters, but I was mistaken.

Comment: If order isn't important, it would be easier to track counts of values and then simply increment/decrement those counts rather than trying to add/remove values.

Comment: Order is important, sorry this wasn't clear, I have clarified the question.

Comment: *how* does order matter? As long as the same numbers appear consecutively in the set (so nothing like `c(1,1,3,4,8,8,10,3)` then storing counts still works, as long as you know the order of the number-groups. You can recreate the result vector with `rep`

Comment: You are right, not sure about the rep() function but with sort I can reorder it.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Thanks for providing minimal reproducible data with question.

Comment: @MKR I try and am learning. I appreciate all of the answers. Now i have to try and pick which answer to accept.

Comment: Let the result come. We can do performance bench-marking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it very simply with `pmatch`:

```
set[-pmatch(played,set)]
# [1]  1  1  3  4  8  8 10
```

And here's another idea:

```
rep.int(seq_len(max(set)),tabulate(set)-tabulate(played,nbins=max(set)))
# [1]  1  1  3  4  8  8 10
```

Comment: I'm trying to break this but I don't seem to be having any luck. I know there are odd results like `pmatch(1, 10)` returns `1`, but I think it should work okay generally.

Comment: Ah... okay - I think I can throw my toys out of the pram - `pmatch(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,3,3,10))` returns `c(5,1,2)` due to partial matching of `"1"` to `"10"` - because `pmatch` uses character comparisons.

Comment: but you'd be playing numbers that aren't in the set :)

Comment: Mmmmmhh.... true. My final attempt at breaking it: `pmatch(c(1,1,10), c(1,10,10))` returns `c(1,3,2)`

Comment: you're still playing numbers that are not in the set, or at least it's an exception that OP should detail because one can't say that any solution here would deal with it "the right way".

Comment: In the second example I'm not I don't think. I only use 1 and 10 on both sides?

Comment: it depends on the game i guess, but if you're pulling cards off a deck, and there's one 1 there, you can't take off 2, what would be the expected output ? lol each time you post I lose my tick mark darn you :D

Comment: Good point. It's a neat answer and I upvoted ages ago. Just making sure it holds up through the character conversion process. (And yes, I'm loving the on-off acceptance. Sorry to be a nuisance!)

Comment: Sorry about removing the acceptance, its there to stay, it just took me some time to double check it works given the breaking attempts etc (new to r). Thank you for the very efficient answer.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate and learnt something cool from it about the function's partial matching. @Hector that's the rules of the game do't worry i said it in all good fun as it was coming back and forth. It's healthy to question the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `table` function:

```
a=table(set)
b=table(played)
a[names(a)%in%names(b)]=a[names(a)%in%names(b)]-b
as.numeric(rep(names(a),a))

[1] 1  1  3  4  8  8 10
```

You can also do:

```
a=merge(table(set),table(played),by.x="set",by.y="played",all=T)
a[is.na(a)]=0
as.numeric(as.character(rep(a$set,a$Freq.x-a$Freq.y)))
[1]  1  1  3  4  8  8 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Still using a loop, but this seems pretty good:

```
p_list = split(played, cumsum(duplicated(played)))
for(p in seq_along(p_list)) {
    set = set[-match(p_list[[p]], set)]
}

set
# [1]  1  1  3  4  8  8 10
```

This breaks `played` up by duplicates so that we can process each piece in a vectorized `match` call.

Comment: This works efficiently, thank you. I will now go about seeing how and why it works.

Answer (score 1):

May be a just simple `for-loop` will do the trick as:

**EDITED:** Based on suggestion from @Gregor.

```
set <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8, 8, 10)
played <- c(1, 3, 1, 4)
#Loop through 'played' and remove from 'set'
for(i in seq_along(played)){
  set <- set[-match(played[i],set)]
}
set
#[1]  1  1  3  4  8  8 10
```

Comment: `match` will probably be faster (and more concise) than `min(which("=="()))`

Answer (score 1):

i have created a function for this :

```
func <- function(set, played){

  for(i in 1:length(played)){
    ll <- which(set == played[i])
    set <- set[-ll[1]]
  }

  return(set)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a `sapply` version, but using `<<-` is somewhat dangerous as it breaks scope

```
sapply(played, function(x) {
  set <<- set[-match(x, set)]
}, simplify = FALSE)
```