# Drop a data.frame from a list of data.frames based on names in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have a list of data.frames. I was wondering how I could delete data.frames in this list whose names are any of the following: `c("out", "Name")`.

I tried   `r[names(r) != c("out", "Name")]` without success.

```
r <- list(
     data.frame(Name = rep("Jacob", 6), 
               X = c(2,2,1,1,NA, NA), 
               Y = c(1,1,1,2,1,NA), 
               Z = rep(3, 6), 
             out = rep(1, 6)), 

 data.frame(Name = rep("Jon", 6), 
               X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
               Y = c(1,1,1,2,NA,NA), 
               Z = rep(2, 6), 
             out = rep(1, 6)), 

  data.frame(Name = rep("Jon", 6), 
                X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
                Y = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), 
                Z = rep(2, 6), 
              out = rep(2, 6)), 

  data.frame(Name = rep("Jim", 6), 
                X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
                Y = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), 
                Z = rep(2, 6), 
              out = rep(1, 6)))
```

Comment: Not sure what the canonical duplicate is, but something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647470/filter-multiple-values-on-a-string-column-in-dplyr/25647535 looks similar or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665984/how-to-delete-multiple-values-from-a-vector

Comment: Not a dupe. Also completely changed the data. This is not about a vector at all.

Comment: Since the question has been changed substantially you might want to edit the title and intro part - sounds like you're not dropping a data.frame from a list, you're dropping columns from data.frames in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
r[!names(r) %in% c("out", "Name")]
```

With the updated data

```
lapply(r, function(x) x[setdiff(names(x), c("out", "Name"))])
```

Comment: @rnorouzian  Because the `list` is not named

Comment: @rnorouzian  In the updated `r`, all the `list` elements are `data.frame` and have columns 'out' or 'Name'.  I guess you want to subset the columns or remove the `liist` element itself if there is a match.  In that case, there won't be any

Comment: @rnorouzian  Okay, if you can update your post with the expected output, it would be great

Comment: @rnorouzian  Going by your description `delete data.frames in this list whose names are any of the following`, all the data.frame have both names, so delete all of them?

Comment: @rnorouzian  You can check `i1 <- !sapply(r, function(x) any(c("out", "Name") %in% names(x))); r[i1]`

Comment: @rnorouzian  If it is based on the output of `split`, `lst1[!names(lst1) %in% c("out", "Name")]`

Comment: Arun here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262597/removing-columns-based-on-a-preset-vector-of-names-in-r)?

Comment: @rnorouzian  I posted a solution there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
r[names(r)!='out'][names(r[names(r)!='out'])!='Name']
```