# Removing columns based on a vector of names in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` called `DATA`. Using **BASE R**, I was wondering how I could remove any variables in `DATA` that is named any of the following: `ar = c("out", "Name", "mdif" , "stder" , "mpre")`?

Currently, I use `DATA[ , !names(DATA) %in% ar]` but while this removes the unwanted variables, it again creates some new nuisance variables suffixed `.1`.

After extraction, is it possible to remove just suffixes?

**Note1:** We have NO ACCESS to `r`, the only input is `DATA`.

**Note2:** This is toy data, a functional solution is appreciated.

```
r <- list(
 data.frame(Name = rep("Jacob", 6), 
           X = c(2,2,1,1,NA, NA), 
           Y = c(1,1,1,2,1,NA), 
           Z = rep(3, 6), 
         out = rep(1, 6)), 

 data.frame(Name = rep("Jon", 6), 
           X = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), 
           Y = c(1,1,1,2,NA,NA), 
           Z = rep(2, 6), 
         out = rep(1, 6)))

DATA <- do.call(cbind, r)  ## DATA

ar = c("out", "Name", "mdif" , "stder" , "mpre") # The names for exclusion

DATA[ , !names(DATA) %in% ar]      ## Current solution
#>
#    X  Y Z X.1 Y.1 Z.1          ## X.1 Y.1 Z.1  are automatically created but no needed
# 1  2  1 3   1   1   2
# 2  2  1 3  NA   1   2
# 3  1  1 3   3   1   2
# 4  1  2 3   1   2   2
# 5 NA  1 3  NA  NA   2
# 6 NA NA 3  NA  NA   2
```

Comment: The variables are created because you have combined two data frames with the same column names. A data frame cannot have two columns with the same name so R adds .1 to each of the duplicates. It has nothing to do with your extraction of specific columns.

Comment: So what is your expected output? Do you want to remove those `.1` variables or you want to remove the suffixes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally column names should be unique but if you want to keep duplicated column names, we can remove `suffixes` using `sub` after extraction

```
DATA1 <- DATA[ , !names(DATA) %in% ar] 
names(DATA1) <- sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(DATA1))

DATA1
#   X  Y Z  X  Y Z
#1  2  1 3  1  1 2
#2  2  1 3 NA  1 2
#3  1  1 3  3  1 2
#4  1  2 3  1  2 2
#5 NA  1 3 NA NA 2
#6 NA NA 3 NA NA 2
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, if we create an object with the index, we can reuse it later instead of doing additional manipulations on the column name

```
i1 <- !names(DATA) %in% ar
DATA1 <- setNames(DATA[i1], names(DATA)[i1])
DATA1
#   X  Y Z  X  Y Z
#1  2  1 3  1  1 2
#2  2  1 3 NA  1 2
#3  1  1 3  3  1 2
#4  1  2 3  1  2 2
#5 NA  1 3 NA NA 2
#6 NA NA 3 NA NA 2
```

For reusuability, we can create a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, vec) {
      i1 <- !names(dat) %in% vec
      setNames(dat[i1], names(dat)[i1])
 }
f1(DATA, ar)
```

If the datasets are stored in a `list`, use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and apply the `f1`

```
lst1 <- list(DATA, DATA)
lapply(lst1, f1, vec = ar)
```

If the 'ar' elements are also different for different `list` elements

```
arLst <- list(ar1, ar2)
Map(f1, lst1, vec = arLst)
```

Here,

```
ar1 <- c("out", "Name")
ar2 <- c("mdif" , "stder" , "mpre")
```

---

Here is also another option using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DATA %>% 
  set_names(make.unique(names(.))) %>% 
  select(-matches(str_c(ar, collapse="|"))) %>%
  set_names(str_remove(names(.), "\\.\\d+$"))
#   X  Y Z  X  Y Z
#1  2  1 3  1  1 2
#2  2  1 3 NA  1 2
#3  1  1 3  3  1 2
#4  1  2 3  1  2 2
#5 NA  1 3 NA NA 2
#6 NA NA 3 NA NA 2
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to have duplicate column names

Comment: I see, by the way, is there any way in Base R, to check if an input file is `csv` or not?