# Remove values from a vector based on a condition

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `x <- c(-10,10)` and I want to remove the values from the vector which absolute value is larger than `8`, how can I achieve that?

I do not want to delete the values by knowing the exact values, which would be `c(-10, -9 , 9 , 10)`, like in this post: [How to delete multiple values from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665984/how-to-delete-multiple-values-from-a-vector)

Comment: `x[abs(x)<=8]` ?

Comment: Indeed, works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this solve your problem:

`x <- x[abs(x) <= 8]`

Answer (score 4):

You have many ways to make it

```
x <- x[abs(x) <= 8]
```

or

```
x <- subset(x,abs(x)<=8)
```

or

```
x <- x[-which(abs(x)>8)]
```

or

```
x <- na.omit(ifelse(abs(x) > 8,NA,x))
```