# Remove an item from a vector using a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have `col.num = 39` and there is a list `z <- c(1,2,3,39,4,5)`

In a loop, I would like to run through the entire list and end up with a list without `col.num`.

What would I like to get in the end `z <- c(1,2,3,4,5)`

What was I trying to do:

```
z <- c(1,2,3,39,4,5)
for(i in 1:length(z))
if(col.num==z[i]){
  print(i)
  
  print(z)
}
```

UPDATE: only using a loop, here is the related post but I need it using a loop:

- [How to delete multiple values from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665984/how-to-delete-multiple-values-from-a-vector)

Comment: Do you have to use loop? Read about `which`, `%in%`, `subset`

Comment: yes, absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code:

```
z <- c(1,2,3,39,4,5)
col.num = 39
for(i in 1:length(z)){
  if(z[i] == col.num){
    z <- z[!z %in% col.num]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove these list levels with a minus `-`:

```
L <- vector("list", 10)
names(L) <- 1:10
L
L <- L[-c(5:6)] # get rid of 5 & 6
names(L)
# [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(z, col.num)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

With loop, it can be

```
for(i in seq_along(z) if(z[i] %in% z) z <- z[-i]
```